# How i can Get the format exemple( 2019-08-27 ) from bsDaterangepicker instead of Wed Aug 28 2019 16:02:24 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00) in Angular

Tags: angular

on My component i have a date input <> when i choose a start and end date like "2019-08-27 - 2019-08-29" it's okey , but when i get the variable on .ts File i get it with other format like [Wed Aug 28 2019 16:02:24 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00), Thu Aug 29 2019 16:02:24 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)]
 there is any solution

NB: I try with variable type string and date, the same issue

component File :

```
 <input 
                    id="D_period" 
                    name="D_period" 
                    [minDate]="minDate"
                    [maxDate]="maxDate" 
                    [(ngModel)]='D_period' 
                    type="text" 
                    bsDaterangepicker 
                    [bsConfig]= "{ adaptivePosition: true, containerClass:'theme-default', rangeInputFormat : 'YYYY-MM-DD', dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY', showWeekNumbers: false }"
                    class="form-control"  >
```

.ts file

```
  D_period:string;
  constructor() { }

  showdate(){
    console.log(this.D_period);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the date and get the format that you want.
Like in this case :

```
initial_date = "Wed Aug 28 2019 16:02:24 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)";
date = new Date(initial_date);
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString();
```

Start with that fiddle for instance: [DateParseJS](https://jsfiddle.net/t40f596h/5/)